# Magento 2: How to translate %changes in email templates

Tags: magento2, email-templates, localisation, magento2.3.0, email-translation

There are some email templates that use variable %changes and I'm not able to translate the text (password) it outputs. How do I translate it? I have tried CSV file with no luck.

Here is an example from the email template:

```
{{trans "New %changes for %user_name" changes=$changes user_name=$user.name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below way..

i have translated in Dutch language

```
"New %changes for %user_name","Nieuwe %changes voor %user_name"
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm in developer mode so do I need to manually delete some caches or other generated files in some folders in order for the translation to work?

Comment: @Webninja you can search this word in your file you have not two time wriiten

Comment: The problem I have is that other parts of that sentence are translated, but the word that goes in place of %changes is not being translated. How do I translate that? For example in my tests this word is: password.

Comment: Dude that's Dutch

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the transactional email section of the admin to load the email template into the database. You can then do a database level store based translation. Even make content changes of you like.